# How to do a CloudKit full text search that includes a token search

Tags: search, full-text-search, nspredicate, cloudkit

I am trying to create a CloudKit text search query.
What does work is a query for the records that starts with the search text like this:

```
NSPredicate(format: "Text BEGINSWITH %@", searchText)!
```

A token search also works (query to see if one of the entered words is somewhere in the record) like this:

```
NSPredicate(format: "allTokens TOKENMATCHES[cdl] %@", searchText)!
```

You can see these queries working in the demo app off [EVCloudKitDao](https://github.com/evermeer/EVCloudKitDao) (see screenshots)

But now I would like to combine these 2 queries so that the results feel a little more complete. I tried using this query:

```
NSPredicate(format: "Text BEGINSWITH %@ OR allTokens TOKENMATCHES[cdl] %@", searchText, searchText)!
```

But then I will get this CloudKit error:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'CKException', reason:
>   'Unexpected expression: Text BEGINSWITH "Y" OR allTokens
>   TOKENMATCHES[cdl] "Y"'

Besides that I also tried a NSCompoundPredicate like this:

```
    var p1 = NSPredicate(format: "allTokens TOKENMATCHES[cdl] %@", searchText)!
    var p2 = NSPredicate(format: "Text BEGINSWITH %@", searchText)!
    var p = NSCompoundPredicate(type: NSCompoundPredicateType.OrPredicateType, subpredicates: [p1, p2])
```

But that one gives about the same error:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'CKException', reason:
>   'Unexpected expression: allTokens TOKENMATCHES[cdl] "y" OR Text
>   BEGINSWITH "y"'

The strange thing is that it does work when using the AndPredicateType instead of the OrPredicateType

Does anyone know an alternate solution for a query like this?
Since it's for an autocomplete function, doing 2 queries and combining the results is not a real option.

Comment: Have you tried to use an NSCompoundPredicate instead?

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Unfortunately it has the same result. It looks like there is a problem with using OR in predicates.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately, joins aren't supported in CloudKit queries. Your only option is to run two separate queries and combine the results of the two in your client.

That's not very efficient, and we're aware of this limitation. If you have the time, a quick radar requesting this feature would be useful.

Update: Per the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/CloudKit/Reference/CKQuery_class/index.html) the only supported compound predicate operators are AND, &&, NOT. The OR operator is not supported in CloudKit. This isn't a bug- it is a known limitation of the server.

Comment: But it's not a join. Its just 2 conditions for one recordType. When using an AND it's OK, when using an OR you will get the error. I think there is a problem with OR queries. I now have the same problem with filtering messages when the predicate is: (from = 'me' and to = 'you') or (from = 'you' and to = 'me')

Comment: Per the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/CloudKit/Reference/CKQuery_class/index.html) the only supported compound predicate operators are `AND, &&, 
NOT`. The `OR` operator is not supported in CloudKit. This isn't a bug- it is a known limitation of the server.

Comment: Argh! Can't believe I have read over that. It's strange that it's not supported. I will add that to the answer. You deserve the bonus.