# Query iCloud public database to find records with properties that contain the search string

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui, icloud, cloudkit

I want to use the iCloud public database to provide my users with items of a certain RecordType "Item":

```
Item: {   
       "name": String, 
       "image": Asset // this is a PNG or JPEG
      }
```

My View contains a TextField where the user can type in a searchText. Whenever the searchText changes, I want to query the iCloud public database for items whose names contain this searchtText.
The code would look something like this:

```
import SwiftUI
import CoreData
import Foundation
import CloudKit


struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var searchText: String = ""
    
    func fetchCloudData() {
        let container = CKContainer.default()
        let publicDB = container.publicCloudDatabase
        let predicate = NSPredicate(value: true)
        let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "name contains %@", searchText)
        
        publicDB.perform(query, inZoneWith: nil) { (records, error) in
            guard error == nil else {
                print("Error fetching records: \(error!)")
                return
            }
            if let records = records {
                records.forEach({ (record) in
                    print(record)
                })
            }
        }
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        TextField("Type in name...", text: $searchText)
        
        Button(action: {
            fetchCloudData()
        }, label: {
            Text("Fetch all items")
        })
    }
}
```

The problem is that the operator **contain** only works on lists and not on strings like the "name" property. There are the operators **BEGINSWITH** and **=**, but they only return those items whose names either begin with or equal the searchText. For example, if the user types in "anan", I want to get an Item with the name "Banana" be returned as well. Is there a way to do this or do I have to resort to downloading every single item at the launch of the app and filter them locally on the device?

**Remark**

There is already a similar question: [How do I perform text search on Cloudkit records?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31459326/how-do-i-perform-text-search-on-cloudkit-records)
The suggested answer was to use

```
NSPredicate(format: @"self contains %@", searchText)
```

For Swift, the @ sign has to be removed so the query works. However, this only queries the records for properties which exactly match the searchText. This does not work if only part of the name matches the searchText.

Answer (score 0):

[Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/cloudkit/ckquery) clearly states:

> With one exception, the **CONTAINS operator is only for testing list membership**. The exception is when you use it to perform full-text searches in conjunction with the self key path. The self key path causes the server to look in searchable string-based fields for the specified token string. For example, a predicate string of @"self contains 'blue'" searches for the word blue in all fields that you mark for inclusion in full-text searches. You can’t use the self key path to search in fields with a type that isn’t a string.

Possibly this question will help you with a full-text search: [How to do a CloudKit full text search that includes a token search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29456476/how-to-do-a-cloudkit-full-text-search-that-includes-a-token-search?rq=1)